# fread() weird behavior in C

Tags: c, file

I have this code that's behaving weirdly when I try setting `max` via different methods.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

int main(int argc,char* argv[])
{
  int max=0;
  FILE* fp=fopen(argv[1],"r");
  FILE* fp1=fopen(argv[2],"w");
  while(fgetc(fp)!=EOF)
    ++max;
  //printf("\n%d\n",max); //933
  char *s=(char*)calloc(max,sizeof(char));
  if(fread(s,sizeof(char),max,fp)==max)
    fwrite(s,sizeof(char),max,fp1);
  else
    fprintf(stderr,"\nError reading file %s\n",argv[1]);
  fclose(fp);
  fclose(fp1);
  return 0;
}
```

As can be seen from the code,I use a *while* loop to find the size of the file (in no.of bytes) and set it to `max`.When `fread` tries reading the file `argv[1]` with "this" max it throws up an error i.e,

```
fread(s,sizeof(char),max,fp)
```

returns 0.

However,when I initialize `max` with the known file size (as calculated by the previous method while commenting out the *while* loop) ,the program produces the expected result.

I have no clue why something like this would happen.Can someone point out where I'm going wrong? Any constructive help would be much appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: `sizeof(char)` is 1.

Comment: need `rewind(fp);` before `fread`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As implied by @BLUEPIXY in comments, the first sequence of operation which computes `max` has the side effects of setting the read location to the end of the file.

Thus, any subsequent `fread` intended to acquired the data fail because there are no more data to be acquired. Resetting the read location to the beginning of the file with:

```
while(fgetc(fp)!=EOF)
  ++max;
rewind(fp); // <------------------ reset read location to start of file.

// go on to read the data
char *s=(char*)calloc(max,sizeof(char));
if(fread(s,sizeof(char),max,fp)==max)
...
```

should resolve the problem.